# VBA from excel to word Find and replace bug

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to create VBA macro that copy a variable entered by user and search for a specific field in text word and replace it  and I tried many codes in stack overflow and other forum but i didn't succeed 
The code below work correctly but it doesn't replace the word , the code search for that field and put the variable next to it . if someone have a solution :D

```
Sub CreateNewWordDoc()
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim i As Integer
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("D:\pfe\DECfinal1.doc")
With wrdDoc
.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "Nombre d'alésage"
.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
.Application.Selection = Sheets("Dec").Range("A2")

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It works just fine for me.

Comment: It works i know but I want to replace that text with my variable not to put the variable next to it . for example  When the there is a variable in excel and I run the macro , he seach for  """ Nombre d'alésage """  and  replace it (( NoT COPY NEXT TO IT ))  with the variable i added in excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said your code works for me. But to be on a safer side, use objects to work with it and do a direct search and replace. See this

```
Sub CreateNewWordDoc()
    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document

    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True

    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\DECfinal89.doc")

    With wrdDoc
        For Each rngStory In .StoryRanges
            Do
                With rngStory.Find
                    .Text = "Nombre d'alésage"
                    .Replacement.Text = Sheets("Dec").Range("A2")
                    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                End With
                Set rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange
            Loop Until rngStory Is Nothing
          Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Nothing happins :'(

Comment: The code that i posted above is tried and tested :). What do you mean "nothing happens"?

Comment: Nothing happens means that  it oppens the word perfectly but then the macro doesn't detect the field with name " nombre d'alésage" and doesn't replace it

Comment: Can i see your word file?

Comment: upload it to any free file sharing site and then share the link here

Comment: U will find the text "" Nombre d'alésage"" in Page 2

Comment: Ah! that is because the text is inside a "Shape". I have updated the post with the code that I am using. You may have to refresh the page to see the edit

Comment: I'm gonna try it  , but that shape must stay there because it's standard to be follow by workers

Comment: Dont worry. my code doesn't do anything to the shape :)

Comment: thank you so much  this worked perfectly how can i reach you if I got something in VBA  macro :D  email or anything

Comment: you dont unless you want to hire me :D You post your queries here in stackoverflow and one of us will help you ;)

Comment: :D thank you so much again . Hope one day your dream come true

Comment: just One more thing if I want to replace many text for example " nombre d'alésage " and " Nominal fasterns" and other   it's  is  possible ?

Comment: can you help me with that aand I will carry on , it will be the last time  :D replace many field with différent variable

Comment: sure. please post a new question with a link to this one and explain what exactly you want to achieve and what have you tried to achieve it. Understand it is important to show what you have tried else your question will attract downvotes and it will get closed.

Comment: I can't link the word file again  you are the only one who know what I 'm trying to Do but thank for what  you did  :D

Comment: Yes I did help you because you showed efforts in this question. Remember stackoverflow is not a code writing service :) You have to show what have you tried. you do not need to link the work file again. simply post a question and link it to this quesiton

Comment: xD ok I'm gonna try  but keep in mind , I'm using VBA for the first time ( One week)

Comment: I did ittt  I found the solution  thank you for encouraging me to think and use my mind

Comment: `I did ittt I found the solution thank you for encouraging me to think and use my mind – POLOS Tutorials 17 secs ago` Glad to be of service ;)